# Get e parameter from a button that hasn't been clicked

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a way that I could access the e event arguments for a button that has not been clicked?

I need to delete multiple entries in a gridview by clicking a button and having it simulate clicking the delete button for each selected entry, but I can't use performClick, so I'm trying to call the actual method that deletes each one. However, that method requires an "e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs" parameter and I can't figure out how to get that.

Comment: If the button does not get clicked the function does not get called. Therefore the EventArg won't be created. You can't get it because it does not exist.

Comment: sounds like you could loop inside the event for the button that **is** clicked

Comment: I am looping inside the event for the Delete Selected button. The problem is calling delete for the individual entries.

Comment: I've called functions like that before by just setting the New keyword to include a new construction of event args.

Comment: Also, maybe you could just pass the same event args parm from the first button click to the second?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access the EventArgs parameter.

I'd suggest you design your code like this:

```
public class MyClass 
{
  private ListView listView;

  protected void OnClick(EventArgs e) 
  {
    performAction();
  }

  private void performAction()
  {
   listView.deleteSelectedItems();
  }
}
```

Don't implement functionality you are going to need somewhere else in delegates. Instead call this functionality inside the delegates' body. This way you can reuse `performAction()` somewhere else ..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem calling delete button can be resolved if you add one check box in each row of datagrid and on click of button Delete you can perform delete operation for the checked rows in following manner

```
 Protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
    CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
     if(chkDelete != null)
     {
      if(chkDelete.Checked)
      {
         strID = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
         ids.Add(strID); //ids can colletion of any type
      }
     }
   }
 }
```

Now send ids to any function to perform delete.